# Pass java script unicode array

Tags: php

I am storing the unicode values in java script array but when I pass it to the ci controller it is not showing in proper language.
How to pass javascript unicode array to php using form post?
My code is:-

```
var myTableArray = [];
$("table#search_result_table tr").each(function() {
var arrayOfThisRow = [];
var tableData = $(this).find('td');
if (tableData.length > 0) {
    tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
    myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
}
});
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myTableArray);
$.post("<?php echo base_url("Purchase/addnew"); ?>",{data:     
myJSON},$("#purform").serialize(),function(data)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent()` when creating post data.

Comment: Code pasted please reply

Answer (score 0):

Santosh, to post Unicode Array through AJAX and JSON, you need 3 files i.e. Javascript file, html file and a php file. Below is the samle code,

### JS file

```js
// make the AJAX request
// #dataform : it is a html data form id
var dataString = $('#dataform').serialize(); 

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'php_file.php',
 data: dataString,
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (data) {
     if (data.success == 0) {
  var errors = '';
  if (data.err_msg != '')
      alert('Error');
     }
     else if (data.success == 1) {
  alert('Success');
     }
 },
 error: function (x,e) {
  alert('Error: '+x.status+','+x.responseText);
 }
});
```

### HTML file

```html
<form id="dataform" name="dataform" method="post" action="" role="form">
 <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
 <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" />
 <input type="text" name="field3" id="field3" />
 <input type="text" name="field4" id="field4" />
 <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### PHP file

```php
$field1=$_REQUEST["field1"];
$field2=$_REQUEST["field2"];
$field3=$_REQUEST["field3"];
$field4=$_REQUEST["field4"];

//Your Validation Logic 
$return_array = validate($field1);
if($return_array['success'] == '1') {
    //Your SQL Query //
}

function validate($field1)
{
    $return_array = array();
    $return_array['success'] = '1';
    $return_array['err_msg'] = '';

    //Validate Field Logic
    if($field1=='')
    {
        $return_array['success'] = '0';
        $return_array['err_msg'] = 'Field1 is required!';
    }

    return $return_array;
}

header('Content-type: text/json');
echo json_encode($return_array);
die();
```